# Lubuntu ISO is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm going to download Lubuntu 32-bit. But when tryig to download from `http://lubuntu.net/`, there's only `lubuntu-10.10.iso`

I don't know whether this is 32-bit or 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Given the focus on resource-constrained (and older) computers, if there's only one, it would be 32-bit. It was when I downloaded a previous release some months back.

Answer (score 1):

Version 10.10 original release is **32-bit**.

Newer releases also support 64-bit.